# How to traverse all components of a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to traverse (loop through) a `JPanel`, with `GridLayout(3,2)`. And for all components in it, if they are an instance of `DescriptionPanel` I want to call their `getHours()` method.

**Question,**

How do I best 'loop through' all components of a `JPanel`?

*my own attempt, which keeps throwing an exception (see below)*

```
double hoursWorked = 0;
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));
.
.
.
for( int i = 0; i < panel.getComponentCount(); i++ ) {
    if(panel.getComponent(i) instanceof DescriptionPanel) {  //DescriptionPanel extends JPanel
        DescriptionPanel dp = (DescriptionPanel) panel.getComponent(i);
        hoursWorked += dp.getHours();
    }
}
```

I have tried to switch `panel.getComponentCount()` to its actualt number (6 in this case). But it keeps throwing the same error message.

```
for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    if(panel.getComponent(i) instanceof DescriptionPanel) {
        DescriptionPanel dp = (DescriptionPanel) panel.getComponent(i);
        hoursWorked += dp.getHours();
    }
 }
```

*Exception*

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 2

Comment: How are the panel's components modified?

Comment: as i read the docs on the awt, they mention that `Component.getComponentCount` method  should be called under AWT tree lock. `Component.getTreeLock`, maybe try this? (synchronize using that lock)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can also reproduce your problem. Your first approach looks OK, so your problem is probably somewhere else. Please don't post your complete code, rather to create a small runnable example that reproduces your exception.

Comment: @PolishCivil they are not in the loop, I just want to call their method getHours, and save the value in the instance variable hoursworked :)

Comment: Yeah, but the component count might have changed during the loop, this is why you should synchronize it.

Comment: Doesn't your first `for` loop (which uses `getComponentCount`) work?

Comment: `getComponentCount` seems to work, but not `getComponent(i)` @PrasadKarunagoda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safest (and in my opinion more  elegant) option here, is to use `getComponents()` method of the panel and iterate through components. Then an instance check of the iterator will do the job.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
for (Component c : panel.getComponents()) {
    if (c instanceof DescriptionPanel)
    {
        DescriptionPanel dp = (DescriptionPanel) c;
        int hours = dp.getHours();
        // Do something with hours
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! :D Works like a charm!
But do you have any idea why `panel.getComponent(i)`in my original loop won't work? I'm just trying to understand!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I will post it as an answer for those who might be wondering why this can occur.

The layout of the components is modified in AWT thread which is probably updating something in the container, thus changing the component's count.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents()

The documentation states that you should synchronize the access to these methods using the `Component.getTreeLock` method.
Such as:

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
synchronized(panel.getTreeLock()) {
for (Component c : panel.getComponents()) {
    if (c instanceof DescriptionPanel)
    {
        DescriptionPanel dp = (DescriptionPanel) c;
        int hours = dp.getHours();
        // Do something with hours
    }
}
}
```